# TFTP-hpa not logging in a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, logging, docker, tftp

I'm running tftpd-hpa on the ubuntu:16.04 base image. When I run this on a full distro it logs fine but inside a docker container there aren't any logs. It seems to be trying to log to /var/log/syslog which is missing. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get some logs from this?

The verbosity is set to 4 which gives suitable verbose output on the full Ubuntu 16.04 install but nothing in the container.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tftpd` does not write to log files on it's own. Rather, it logs via syslog (it opens `/dev/log` and writes messsages there, which are collected by some sort of logging daemon and then dispatched to files based on its configuration).

Inside a typical container there is no logging daemon, so nothing is listening on `/dev/log` and your log messages simply disappear.

If you want to see those logs when running `tftpd` inside a container, you will need to have something listen on `/dev/log`.  You have several options:

- You can mount your host's `/dev/log` inside the container by adding `-v /dev/log:/dev/log` to your `docker run` command line; this will make log messages from `tftpd` in the container appear in your host's `/var/log/...` files (final destination dependent on your syslog configuration, but generally something like `/var/log/messages`).
- You can run a minimal syslog service in the container and it log to a file.  For example, you could install `busybox` and then run `busybox syslogd` before you start the `tftpd` service.  For example, your `CMD` might look like:

  ```
  CMD ["sh", "-c", "busybox syslogd; in.tftpd -Lvvv"]
  ```

  In this case, the logs would be visible in `/var/log/messages` *inside* the container.
- Instead of writing logs to a file, you could redirect them to the container's stdout.  If you modify the above command to have `busybox syslogd` write to stdout, like this...

  ```
  CMD ["sh", "-c", "busybox syslogd -n -O /dev/stdout & in.tftpd -Lvvv"]
  ```

  ...then you will see logs on your container's console, where they will also be collected by Docker and made available via `docker logs`.

This isn't an exhaustive list of solutions, but hopefully it's enough to point you towards a solution.